# Give an example of a function $h:\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\ \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: functions, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

The question is

> $h:\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\ \mathbb{Q}$ so that the
> image of $h$ is the **same** as the codomain of $h$.

I couldn't really think of a function that maps irrational numbers to rational numbers. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: One method would be to think of an invertible function $g: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$; and then map all the un-mapped-to irrationals to, say, zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$h(x)=r$ if $x=\sqrt2+r$ for some $r\in\mathbb Q$, and $h(x)=0$ else.

Comment: Clever! :) :) :)

Answer (score 7):

Use the floor of the absolute value,
$$x\mapsto⌊|x|⌋\ :\ {\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb Q}\,\to\,{\mathbb N}$$
which is surjective, and further use that ${\mathbb Q}$ is countable.

Comment: The floor function would only produce $\mathbb{N}$ right? The question is actually asking me to find a function whose range is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @d0nut Yeah for brievity the answer takes for granted that ${\mathbb Q}$ and ${\mathbb N}$ have the same cardinality. Here's a pointer to the relevant [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Countability) and you'll find counting functions on this site too.