# Does a Lipschitz continuous surjection $f:\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

**Question:**

> Does a Lipschitz continuous surjection $f:\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ exist?

Without the restriction on $f$ being Lipschitz continuous the answer is yes: [Give an example of a function $h:\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\ \mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542796/give-an-example-of-a-function-h-mathbbr-backslash-mathbbq-rightarrow-mat/4542799#4542799).

The intuitive reason why I restrict $f$ to be Lipschitz continuous and not only continuous is that I expect a Lipschitz continuous function on a dense subset of an interval $I$ to have similar properties as if it was continuous on $I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The answer is no.*

**Proof:** Suppose to the contrary that there was such a Lipschitz continuous surjection $f:\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$. Then by [Kirszbraun theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem) it could be extended into a function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ the is Lipschitz continuous as well. Consider any $a,b\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Then since $g$ is continuous (on $\mathbb R$),
$$
[g(a),g(b)] \subset g[a,b]
= f([a,b]\setminus \mathbb Q) \,\cup\, g([a,b]\cap \mathbb Q),
$$
where $[g(a),g(b)]$ is an uncountable set, whilst both $f([a,b]\setminus \mathbb Q)\subset \mathbb Q$ and $g([a,b]\cap \mathbb Q)$ are both countable.
$\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: Kirszbraun theorem is overkill and uniform continuity (or even [Cauchy-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function)) is sufficient.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks a lot for sharing your observation, you made a very good point.